# Two tricky derivative problems

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

1. Find $F'(x)$ for $F(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\sqrt{1-t^{2}}\,dt$.
2. Find $F '(x)$ for $F(x)=\int_{x^{2}}^{3}\sin(t^{2})\,dt$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you learn about the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: yes. thats f(b)-f(a) right? @OfekGillon

Comment: @A.Ferris I set your question in [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Make sure I interpreted it correctly.

Comment: @DMcMor yeah thats correct

Comment: Actually that's not what I meant (this is a straight conclusion from it and is called Newton-Leibniz formula), but I can work with that.

Ask yourself, if 
$$ F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt $$ 
then
$$ F'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{F(x+\Delta x) - F(x)}{\Delta x} = ?$$

Comment: @OfekGillon ok how do i use that to solve the problem?

Comment: First solve the question I wrote in the comment, after that things will be clear

Comment: Looks like you listing off your homework problems expecting us to do all of it for you. Unlike some Q/A sites, you must show effort or your questions will be closed and you will be [suspended from asking more questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) until you are of site quality. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [Information to new users](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11628/information-to-new-users) and [our norms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17286/what-are-the-general-norms-on-this-site)

Answer (score 1):

I won't provide solutions but rather outline what you would do. The key is this: for appropriate $f$, let

$$ F(x) = \int_a ^x f(t) \ dt $$

for $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $F'(x) = f(x)$. In order words, evaluate the integrand at the upper limit of integration.

Notice something, though, that this holds when the lower limit is a constant and the upper limit is a variable. If, say, we have

$$ G(x) = \int_x ^a g(t) \ dt $$

then $G'(x) = -g(x)$ by the rule that

$$ \int_a ^b f = -\int_b ^a f $$

so you must be careful with signs. Now, if we have the function

$$ H(x) = \int_a ^{u(x)} h(t) \ dt $$

then we employ the chain rule to obtain

$$ H'(x) = h(u(x)) u'(x) $$.

The same issue with retaining signs holds here. I hope this helps you understanding the process of differentiating functions defined as integrals.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is simply $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. The second one is slightly more tricky. We reverse the limits like so $$F(x) = -\int_3^{x^2} \sin t^2 \, \mathrm{d}t$$ so that we can use the chain rule and the FToC in conjunction to get $$-2x\sin\left(x^2\right)^2 = -2x\sin x^4.$$

---

The fundamental theorem of calculus actually states that if $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$ for constant $a$ and $f$ a continuous function on $[a,b]$ then $F'(x) = f(x)$ with $F$ differentiable on $(a,b)$ and continuous on $[a,b]$.

Comment: thank you so much, totally understand it now

Comment: To be accurate, this the *first fundamental theorem* The *second fundamental theorem* asserts the integral is equal $F(b)-F(a)$ ((which many beginners think is the *definition* of the integral).

Answer (score 0):

The first is really just the FTC. I will do the second, since it may be somewhat tricky the first time around.

Let $u(x)=x^2$, then your given integral is 
$$
F(x)=\int_{u(x)}^3\sin(t^2)\mathrm dt =-\int_3^{u(x)}\sin(t^2)\mathrm dt\\ \stackrel{\text{FTC+Chain rule}}{\implies} F'(x)=-\sin(u(x)^2)u'(x)\\
=-2x\sin(x^4)
$$